# Crystal Report Change Datasource Swap Dev to QA

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Trying to add a new DB field to an existing crystal report file with unknown/no-access datasource.

1. Grabbed the .rpt file from QA server ,
2. Opened in Local VS2019
3. Checked 'Set Datasource Location'

[image]

1. Now , Changed the connection to Local DB to add the new field
2. Checked 'Set Datasource Location' again

[image]

Now I put the file back to QA server and run the job but getting error in log files

> Failed to open the connection. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 53 ]

Now question is, is there a way to set the initial datasource after making the changes with thelocal datasource. Developer will have access to only dev DB's, and initial datasource was of QA DB I guess, its basically unknown.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Designer, use ***Database, Verify Database...*** to synchronize the data structure Crystal expects with the updated database structure.

You can avoid the need to change data source properties by using ODBC connection instead of OLEDB.